# book recommendation for distributed algorithms (to understand zookeeper, consul, etcd, mesos, etc.)

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, mesos

Is there a modern distributed systems book which explains the algorithms behind tools such as zookeeper, consul, etcd, mesos, etc.

I'm not looking for descriptions of these specific tools. All of them are obviously built to solve problems of building distributed systems: deployment, monitoring, state management, locking, maintaining counters, consistency trade offs, etc.

Rather than reading any number of blog posts on the CAP theorem or scanning stack overflow to understand RAFT vs paxos or watching youtube presentations on config/monitoring/deployment of thousands of processes across 100s of machines, I would like a book which lays the foundations.

I do see that there are some text books on distributed computing, but most of them seem to have been written decades ago. I get the impression (possibly wrong) that there have been a number of improvements in the past 5-10 years. For example, the raft paper seems to have been published in 2014. Mesos is built on ideas from a paper written only a few years ago.

Lastly, I'm not trying to understand all these algorithms in detail. Just enough that I have context for the current ecosystem and the ability to comprehend advances coming in the next few years - along with understanding how to use these ideas in real software development.

Comment: There are several answers to this question here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11911402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these:

- [Notes on Theory of Distributed Systems](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/classes/465/notes.pdf)
- [Principles of Distributed Computing](http://disco.ethz.ch/lectures/podc_allstars/)
- [Distributed Algorithms](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/distalgs.html)
- [Werner Vogels' home page](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/)

First two are free resources, third is a hardcover, last one is Amazon's CTO's home page. Hope these help!